# Facing issue with GCM - Message not received on device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the google guidelines for setting up GCM on my device and the server side. I successfully got the device registration ID and when I use it to send a message using the sever side code given by google, I am getting success as well. But no message is received on my phone. Please help.

Comment: I am doing this for a phonegap project. I used all the classes mentioned here https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova . Just that instead of invoking the registration from a JS, I called                        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "620217706951"); in mainActivity. I added the same SENDER_ID in overridden constructor of GCMIntentService as well.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), understand the concept and refer class `GCMIntentService`.

Comment: Referred the link. The android side set up of mine is very similar. However, I am using the google provided jar and code as given in the link:http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Use notification manager to display message and a broadcast receiver for displaying notification that you are getting and i hope you are using sever API key

Answer (score 1):

According to [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html), GCM uses ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 to send messages. If you do everything right but still not receiving the message, ask your web administrator and confirm that these ports are open.

Comment: I checked my all three port and seems all three ports are close. But still I am able to receive the message. Can u tell me why???

Comment: If you can get the message even closing all those ports, GCM might also use other ports to send message which are not written in the document.

Comment: and any doc. which backs up your comment!!! Not just because I doubt your comment(which I seriously do), but also it will help me understand the concept and reason for doing so...

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. I meant... I don't think it would work if not opening the ports unless there are other used ports which are not in doc. I once had the same problem as the title, and I solved it by opening ports. So I'm afraid I can't tell why you could do that!